# Householder Transformation

Tags: numerical-methods, orthogonality

Whilst studying for an exam, I stumbled over this question which is actually made of 3 parts:

**(a) What is the most simple form we can obtain orthogonal Householder transformations?**

I am thinking to decompose a matrix A to an orthogonal matrix Q and an upper triangular matrix R: `A = Q * R`

**(b) In which case the Householder transformation is the most efficient?**

For this case, I am thinking when applying the transformation on a matrix A to make it in a tridiagonal matrix. Let's say that A is of `nxn` size. That means in order to make A a tridiagonal matrix you have to do `n-2` steps. On the other hand, to transform `A = Q * R`, basically you are performing `n-1` steps.

**(c) Explain why the orthogonal transformations Householder & Givens can also be considered factorizations?**

Not really sure, but I would say that at each step basically you are building an upper trian. matrix or a tridiagonal matrix that is based on factorizations?

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying a matrix $A$ by an appropriate sequence of Givens or Householder transformations one obtains an upper triangular matrix $R$. That is,

$$
Q_k^T\ldots Q_1^T A = R
$$

If we let $Q = Q_1\ldots Q_k$, we have $A = QR$, which is the well-known QR factorization of the matrix $A$. Note that in practice, Householder transformations are typically preferred when $A$ is a dense matrix, whereas Givens rotations are preferred when working with sparse matrices.

Comment: That clears the dust a little, especially for (c), however, what about (a)? That's the one that really bugs me.

Comment: I don't quite understand the wording of part (a). Normally a Householder transformation is expressed as $H = I - 2uu^T$, where $u$ is a unit vector in the $2$-norm.